# C# Foreach loop, help to implement move to NEXT and PRIVIOUS step

Tags: c#, .net-core, plc

Here is the code I have written so far, which I haven't tested yet with a real PLC. I wonder if there is a way to implement the previous step and move to the next step?

```
public async void Run()
{
    //recepi has many steps, and each step has one or many Nodes (commands to PLC)
    foreach (Step step in recepi.Step)
    {
        var spStep = new TagItem(step.SPTag, daServer);//setpoint to the PLC
        var pvStep = new TagItem(step.SPTag, daServer);//actual Process value from PLC

        foreach (var node in step.Nodes)
        {
            // here i'm writing other setpoints to the PLC.
            var spNode = new TagItem(node.SPTag, daServer);
            await spNode.Write(node.Value);
        }

        //when all the commands are sent to the PLC, i have to wait for the prosess value to reach a certn 
        //value before i can move to next step and do the same again.

        switch (step.Operator)
        {
            case Operator.Equal:
                System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => (float.Parse(pvStep.TagValue) == float.Parse(spStep.TagValue)));
                break;
            case Operator.Unequal:
                System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => (float.Parse(pvStep.TagValue) != float.Parse(spStep.TagValue)));
                break;
            case Operator.LessThan:
                System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => (float.Parse(pvStep.TagValue) < float.Parse(spStep.TagValue)));
                break;
            case Operator.LessThanOrEqual:
                System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => (float.Parse(pvStep.TagValue) <= float.Parse(spStep.TagValue)));
                break;
            case Operator.GreaterThan:
                System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => (float.Parse(pvStep.TagValue) > float.Parse(spStep.TagValue)));
                break;
            case Operator.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => (float.Parse(pvStep.TagValue) >= float.Parse(spStep.TagValue)));
                break;
        }
    }        
}
```

Thank you for you help!

In the UI The operator can Stop,Pause,Go to next and previous step by pressing respective buttons. what I want to achieve is smiler to music player. Running a recipe takes more than 2 hours to finish the batch, since its a slow process, where heating is involved.

Here is the code I have at the moment using the Stateless library for the state machine.

```
using Formula.Models;
using Formula.UI;
using Stateless;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class FormulaEngine
{
    private readonly StateMachine<RecepieState, Triggers> _machine;
    StateMachine<RecepieState, Triggers>.TriggerWithParameters<Step> _setNextStep;
    StateMachine<RecepieState, Triggers>.TriggerWithParameters<Step> _setPreviousStep;
    private readonly DAServer _daServer;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _ea;
    const float Epsilon = 0.001f;
    private int _index = 0;

    StepList stepList;
    public Recepi Recepi { get; }

    Dictionary<Operator, Func<TagItem,Step, bool>> operatorItems = new Dictionary<Operator, Func<TagItem, Step, bool>>
    {
        { Operator.Equal, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) < Epsilon) },
        { Operator.Unequal, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) > Epsilon) },
        { Operator.LessThan, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) < Epsilon) },
        { Operator.LessThanOrEqual, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) <= Epsilon) },
        { Operator.GreaterThan, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) > Epsilon) },
        { Operator.GreaterThanOrEqual, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) >= Epsilon) },
    };

    public enum RecepieState
    {
        Running,
        Stoped,
        Paused
    }
    public enum Triggers
    {
        Start,
        Pause,
        Stop,
        GoToNextStep,
        GoToPreviousStep            
    }

    public FormulaEngine(Recepi recepi, DAServer daServer, IEventAggregator ea)
    {
        Recepi = recepi;
        this._daServer = daServer;
        this._ea = ea;
        _machine = new StateMachine<RecepieState, Triggers>(RecepieState.Stoped);

        _setNextStep = _machine.SetTriggerParameters<Step>(Triggers.GoToNextStep);
        _setPreviousStep = _machine.SetTriggerParameters<Step>(Triggers.GoToPreviousStep);
        ConfigureStateMachine();
        stepList = new StepList();
        stepList.AddSteps(Recepi.Step);
    }

    private void ConfigureStateMachine()
    {
        _machine.Configure(RecepieState.Running)
            .OnEntryAsync(t => ExcecuteRecepi())
            .InternalTransitionAsync(Triggers.GoToNextStep, t => OnNextStep())
            .InternalTransitionAsync(Triggers.GoToPreviousStep, t => OnPreviousStep())
            //.OnEntryFromAsync(Triggers.StartExcecuting, (t) => ExcecuteRecepi())
            //.OnEntryAsync(t => StartTimer())
            //.OnExitAsync(t => StopTimer())
            //.InternalTransitionAsync(_setNextStep, (step, t) => OnNextStep(step))                
            //.InternalTransitionAsync(_setPreviousStep, (step, t) => OnPreviousStep(step))
            .Permit(Triggers.Pause, RecepieState.Paused)
            .Permit(Triggers.Stop, RecepieState.Stoped);

        _machine.Configure(RecepieState.Paused)
            .Permit(Triggers.Start, RecepieState.Running)
            .Permit(Triggers.Stop, RecepieState.Stoped);

        _machine.Configure(RecepieState.Stoped)
            .Permit(Triggers.Start, RecepieState.Running);
    }      

    public int Index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set
        { 
            _index = value;
            _ea.GetEvent<CurrentStepChangedEvent>().Publish(_index);
        }
    }
    private async Task ExcecuteRecepi()
    {
        Index = 0;
        stepList.CurrentStepIndex = Index;
        if (Index <= stepList.Count())
        {
            var step = stepList[Index];
            await RunStep(step);
        }
        await _machine.FireAsync(Triggers.GoToNextStep);

    }

    private async Task<bool> RunStep(Step step)
    {

        var pvStep = new TagItem(step.SPTag, _daServer);
        foreach (var node in step.Nodes)
        {
            // here i'm writing other setpoints to the PLC.
            var spNode = new TagItem(node.SPTag, _daServer);
            await spNode.Write(node.Value);
        }
        var test = operatorItems[step.Operator];
        while (!test(pvStep, step))
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }          

        return true;
    }

    private async Task OnPreviousStep()
    {
        if(Index > 0)
        {
            Index--;
            if (Index <= stepList.Count())
            {
                var step = stepList[Index];
                await RunStep(step);
            }
        }

    }

    private async Task<bool> OnNextStep()
    {
        Index++;
        if (Index <= stepList.Count())
        {
            var step = stepList[Index];
            await RunStep(step);
            //var result = Task.Run(async () => await RunStep(step)).Result;
            _machine.Fire(Triggers.GoToNextStep);
        }
        return true;
    }

    //private Task StopTimer()
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}

    //private Task StartTimer()
    //{
    //    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    //    stopWatch.Start();
    //}

    public void Stop()
    {
        _machine.Fire(Triggers.Stop);
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        _machine.Fire(Triggers.Pause);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _machine.FireAsync(Triggers.Start);

    }

}
```

---

```
using Formula.Models;
using Formula.UI;
using Stateless;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FormulaEngine
{

    public enum Activity
    {

        WAIT_UNTIL = 1
    }
    public enum RecepieState
    {
        Running,
        Stoped,
        Paused
    }
    public enum Triggers
    {
        Start,
        Pause,
        Stop,
        GoToNextStep,
        GoToPreviousStep,
        StartExcecuting
    }

    public enum Operator
    {
        [Description("=")]
        [EnumMember(Value = "=")]
        Equal,

        [Description("<>")]
        [EnumMember(Value = "<>")]
        Unequal,

        [Description("<")]
        [EnumMember(Value = "<")]
        LessThan,

        [Description("<=")]
        [EnumMember(Value = "<=")]
        LessThanOrEqual,

        [Description(">")]
        [EnumMember(Value = ">")]
        GreaterThan,

        [Description(">=")]
        [EnumMember(Value = ">=")]
        GreaterThanOrEqual
    }
    public class BaseModel
    {
        public short Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Recepi : BaseModel
    {
        public Recepi()
        {
            Step = new List<Step>();
        }

        public short FormulaGroupId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RecepiId")]
        public List<Step> Step { get; set; }

    }

    public class Step : BaseModel
    {
        public Step()
        {
            Nodes = new List<Node>();
        }
        public short RecepiId { get; set; }
        public short SPTagId { get; set; }
        public short PVTagId { get; set; }
        public Operator Operator { get; set; }
        public TagMetaData SPTag { get; set; }
        public TagMetaData PVTag { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Activity Activity { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StepId")]
        public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    }
    public class Node : BaseModel
    {
        public short StepId { get; set; }
        public short SPTagId { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
        public TagMetaData SPTag { get; set; }
        public TagMetaData PVTag { get; set; }
        public Operator Operator { get; set; }
    }
    public class TagMetaData : BaseModel, IComparable<TagMetaData>
    {
        //public GroupMetaData GroupMetaData { get; set; }


        public short GroupId { get; set; }
        public string EngUnit { get; set; }

        public DateTime CurrentTimeStamp { get; set; }

        public int CurrentQuality { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public DataType DataType { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ushort Size { get; set; }

        public float Maximum { get; set; }

        public float Minimum { get; set; }

        public int Cycle { get; set; }


        public TagMetaData(short id, string name, short grpId, string address, DataType type, ushort size, float max = 0, float min = 0, int cycle = 0)
        {
            Id = id;
            GroupId = grpId;
            Name = name;
            Address = address;
            DataType = type;
            Size = size;
            Maximum = max;
            Minimum = min;
            Cycle = cycle;
        }

        public TagMetaData()
        {
        }

        public int CompareTo(TagMetaData other)
        {
            return this.Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
    public class FormulaEngine
    {
        private readonly StateMachine<RecepieState, Triggers> _machine;
        private readonly DAServer daServer;
        const float Epsilon = 0.001f;
        int Index = 0;
        public Recepi Recepi { get; }

        Dictionary<Operator, Func<TagItem, Step, bool>> operatorItems = new Dictionary<Operator, Func<TagItem, Step, bool>>
            {
                { Operator.Equal, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) < Epsilon) },
                { Operator.Unequal, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) > Epsilon) },
                { Operator.LessThan, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) < Epsilon) },
                { Operator.LessThanOrEqual, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) <= Epsilon) },
                { Operator.GreaterThan, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) > Epsilon) },
                { Operator.GreaterThanOrEqual, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.Value)) >= Epsilon) },
            };

        public enum RecepieState
        {
            Running,
            Stoped,
            Paused
        }
        public enum Triggers
        {
            Start,
            Pause,
            Stop,
            GoToNextStep,
            GoToPreviousStep,
            StartExcecuting
        }

        public FormulaEngine(Recepi recepi, DAServer daServer)
        {
            Recepi = recepi;
            this.daServer = daServer;
            _machine = new StateMachine<RecepieState, Triggers>(RecepieState.Stoped);
            ConfigureStateMachine();
        }

        private void ConfigureStateMachine()
        {
            _machine.Configure(RecepieState.Running)
                .OnEntryAsync(t => ExcecuteRecepi())
                //.OnEntryFromAsync(Triggers.StartExcecuting, (t) => ExcecuteRecepi())
                //.OnEntryAsync(t => StartTimer())
                //.OnExitAsync(t => StopTimer())
                .InternalTransitionAsync(Triggers.GoToNextStep, t => OnNextStep())
                .InternalTransitionAsync(Triggers.GoToPreviousStep, t => OnPreviousStep())
                .Permit(Triggers.Pause, RecepieState.Paused)
                .Permit(Triggers.Stop, RecepieState.Stoped);

            _machine.Configure(RecepieState.Paused)
                .Permit(Triggers.Start, RecepieState.Running)
                .Permit(Triggers.Stop, RecepieState.Stoped);

            _machine.Configure(RecepieState.Stoped)
                .Permit(Triggers.Start, RecepieState.Running);
        }

        private async Task ExcecuteRecepi()
        {
            var stepList = new StepList();
            stepList.AddSteps(Recepi.Step);
            var step = stepList[Index];
            await RunStep(step);
        }

        private async Task RunStep(Step step)
        {
            var pvStep = new TagItem(step.SPTag, daServer);
            foreach (var node in step.Nodes)
            {
                // here i'm writing other setpoints to the PLC.
                var spNode = new TagItem(node.SPTag, daServer);
                await spNode.Write(node.Value);
            }
            var test = operatorItems[step.Operator];
            while (!test(pvStep, step))
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
            Index++;
            await _machine.FireAsync(Triggers.GoToNextStep);
        }

        private async Task OnPreviousStep()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private async Task OnNextStep()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //private Task StopTimer()
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}

        //private Task StartTimer()
        //{
        //    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        //    stopWatch.Start();
        //}

        public void Stop()
        {
            _machine.Fire(Triggers.Stop);
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            _machine.Fire(Triggers.Pause);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _machine.FireAsync(Triggers.Start);
            _machine.FireAsync(Triggers.StartExcecuting);
        }

    }
    public class StepList : IEnumerable<Step>
    {
        private Dictionary<int, Step> _stepList;
        private readonly object cacheSyncLock;

        public StepList()
        {
            this._stepList = new Dictionary<int, Step>();
            this.cacheSyncLock = new object();
        }

        public void AddSteps(List<Step> stepList)
        {
            foreach (Step step in stepList)
            {
                int newIndex = this._stepList.Keys.Count == 0 ? 0 : this._stepList.Keys.Max() + 1;

                this._stepList.Add(newIndex, step);
            }

        }

        public IEnumerator<Step> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this._stepList
                .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)
                .Select(pair => pair.Value)
                .GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public Step this[int index]
        {
            get { return this._stepList[index]; }
        }
        public int? CurrentStepIndex { get; set; }

        public bool CanRunNextStep
        {
            get { return this.CurrentStepIndex.HasValue && this._stepList.ContainsKey(this.CurrentStepIndex.Value + 1); }
        }

        public bool CanRunPreviousStep
        {
            get { return this.CurrentStepIndex.HasValue && this._stepList.ContainsKey(this.CurrentStepIndex.Value - 1); }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: please define "better", since this is a completely subjective term.

Comment: A question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should return `Task` instead of `void`

Comment: Maybe you could create and use an Enumeration Class instead on this simple enum. [This MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) might help you to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement the previous step and move to the next step"?

Comment: Was my answer of any use (if you get nothing else out of it, make sure you understand what I'm saying about comparing `float` values)?  If you want help on how to "implement the previous step and move to the next step", you will have to tell us what you mean (as @Enigmativity points out).  Can you flesh out what the state machine I think you are describing means (and how you expect it to work).  I suspect the answer to your question is pretty simple - however, no one really understands what the question you want to ask really is.

Comment: Hi Flydog57, yes very much. Thank you for the Answer. I haven't been able to test with a real PLC yet, Since I'm having trouble with my PLC driver code. Can you also point me in the right direction when it comes to moving to the next step and the previous Step?

Comment: @GajarubanJeyakumar: If you want me to see your comments to me, prepend my name with a `@`. You will need to explain what you mean by next/prev step.  I'm assuming that this is a very simple batch recipe system. But, your code is way too simple; your recipe is simply a set of steps-each adjusting setpoints on a set of tags, and then waiting until one of your measurements hits the value you are targeting. To allow for next/prev, you'd need some manual input. In addition, you don't seem to have any concept of time, nor of opening/closing valves, starting mixers, etc. This needs explanation

Comment: @Flydog57 Thankyou. I have edited the question with more information. as you are pointing out, I need a concept of time, I haven't thought about it. since I'm  just now starting to figure out how to do this.

Comment: @GajarubanJeyakumar: I greatly updated my answer.  There's not a lot of programming help there (it's mostly rough design), but it's all I've got for you.

Comment: @GajarubanJeyakumar - Are you saying that you want to replace the `foreach (Step step in recepi.Step)` with the ability to manually go backwards and forwards through the `recepi.Step`? You really need to provide your class definitions at least and probably closer to a [mcve] for us to give you a real solid answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thankyou. Please see my latest edit. I'm trying to implement a state machine at the moment, I believe I need to change the foreach loop to a for loop to achieve manually going forward and backward, by changing the index value.

Comment: @Enigmativity Please see my code so far. 
https://pastebin.com/7rFM98CJ

Comment: @GajarubanJeyakumar - It's really hard to help when people don't follow through on what you ask. Please can we have class definitions?

Comment: @Enigmativity I misunderstood you. Please see https://pastebin.com/7rFM98CJ. I have updated with all the classes necessary to reproduce. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Enigmativity Please see my UI(updated Question with picture), it may give you a better idea on what I want to achieve, Thank you.

Comment: @GajarubanJeyakumar - Thank you. Please don't post code to an external site when it can just be put in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(**First a note**: Most of your readers will not have a clue what a PLC is.  I'm guessing it's a Programmable Logic Controller.  You might want to call that out, and roughly describe it in your question)*

I'm leaving my original answer at the bottom of this - it still make good points about the programming in your question.  The new parts (immediately below) are less about programming and more about design.

Also note that I haven't done anything like this (controls systems, PLCs and batch systems) in a little over 20 years and of those three areas, I have the least experience in batch systems.  By the way, does your PLC support a language like IEC-61131-3/SFC?  The 1131-3 Sequential Function Chart language was really developed to program batch and recipe systems.

---

In order to allow *"The operator can Stop, Pause, Go to Next and Previous step by pressing respective buttons"*, you will likely have to radically restructure your program.  You will also want to make everything asynchronous.

Ten years ago, I would have recommended doing the control part in a dedicated thread and having the UI communicate through a queue or some other asynchronous mechanism.  I suspect that you can do this now by making just about *everything* awaitable.

You are probably want to make your recipe steps much richer.  As I understand it, your recipe steps now consist of a set of tag/setpoint pairs and then a *step-completed* condition that consists of a single tag, a setpoint and a comparison operation.

You might want to consider this in your recipe steps:

- The concept of time (how long to hold a particular state)
- That a step may not only involved changing setpoints, but also starting/stopping or opening/closing things
- That the end of a step may be complicated (time, measurement, or measurements)
- That measurement "equality" many not be good enough.  It's not uncommon for a measured quantity to overshoot the setpoint by 20-25% and then ring a bit before settling down.  You may want to consider having "equality" optionally mean "within N% of setpoint for T seconds".

In addition, to get your pause/stop/next/prev behavior, you are not going to just loop over your steps.  Instead, create a class that maintains an ordered collection of steps and accepts commands to pause/stop/next/prev.  Then implement a state machine that involves the steps, the commands, and a set of intermediate states.

What I mean by "intermediate states" is that a command to, for example, pause a step will not immediately cause the step to pause.  Instead, it will go through a "waiting to pause" state and then get to the paused state.  Make your commands `await`able.  When the UI calls `await Pause()`, the task it returns will eventually complete when the state enters the Paused state.  The same thing for stopped, next and previous.

A variation on the little loop that I showed in the original answer:

```
while (!test(spStep, pvStep))
{
    await Task.Delay(pollingTime);
}
```

may be enough to "power" your state engine.  You run a simple polling loop.  The condition on the loop would be more complex than I show and there will likely be quite a bit of code after the call to `Task.Delay`. But something like this would allow you to sense when time is up, when a state should transition, etc.

You many need to have rules (encoded in your steps) that prevent the operator entering unsafe states, and then have code to always always bring a step to a safe state (for example, if you are mixing two components and the only safe state is "neither A nor B" in the tank or "all of A and B in the tank", you need to somehow encode that information.  Remember the first level of a control system is safety.

When you are in automatic mode, all that happens is when a step completes, it just calls a "Next" command on itself (until it gets to the end of the recipe).

---

**Another note on equality**

If you read up on comparing floats and doubles, you will see lots of information about how to appropriately decide if two numbers are equal - based on the range of `float` and of `double`.  In control systems, measurements many be inexact, have hysteresis and be noisy.  You will likely want to do comparison based not on the range of `float`, but on the range of the measurement.  I seem to remember one system that I worked on had a "coarse", "medium" or "fine" property associated with every measurement.  For example, "coarse" could mean that two measurements that were within 2% of the measured scale would be considered "equal".

---

**Finally**

Don't forget that if you find this useful, you can up-vote it.  And, if it answers your question, you can "accept" it.

---

**Original Answer:**

My understanding is that `System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil` is very heavy and very easy to misuse.  I am in no way an expert in its use, I've avoided it.

However, what you probably want to do is something that is awaitable anyway.  I don't know what your timing requirements are (it's literally been decades since I touched a PLC).  However, I'm guessing that if you polled your values every 50 millisecond you'd get the response you need.

First, as noted in the comments, your function should be `async Task` not `async void`.  You may also want to rename it to `RunAsync`.  So:

```
public async Task RunAsync()
```

Since your core operations code is so similar, I'm tempted to drive it with a table.  So consider something like this:

```
Dictionary<Operator, Func<TagItem, TagItem, bool>> operatorItems =
    new Dictionary<Operator, Func<TagItem, TagItem, bool>>
    {
        { Operator.Equal, (p,s) => (float.Parse(p.TagValue) == float.Parse(s.TagValue)) },
        { Operator.Unequal, (p,s) => (float.Parse(p.TagValue) != float.Parse(s.TagValue)) },
        { Operator.LessThan, (p,s) => (float.Parse(p.TagValue) < float.Parse(s.TagValue)) },
        { Operator.LessThanOrEqual, (p,s) => (float.Parse(p.TagValue) <= float.Parse(s.TagValue)) },
        { Operator.GreaterThan, (p,s) => (float.Parse(p.TagValue) > float.Parse(s.TagValue)) },
        { Operator.GreaterThanOrEqual, (p,s) => (float.Parse(p.TagValue) >= float.Parse(s.TagValue)) },
    };
```

Here I build a table that maps the Operator to the condition to test for.

One thing to note is that you are working with floats.  Comparing floats for equality (actually for equality, inequality, and, do a lesser extent, less than or greater than) is the wrong thing thing to do.  Look on the internet and you can find lots of discussion about why you should ***never*** do this.

You should define an *Epsilon* value that represents "close enough to be considered equal*.  Depending on what you are reading (i.e., how noisy the PLC signal is (if it's a digitized analog signal)), this might be rather small (or not).  It also depends on the range of values you have.  In addition, if the values you are reading can very widely in range, then you might not want to use a constant, but instead using something that is a fraction of the size of the values you are looking at.

But, to keep it simple let's do something like this:

```
const float Epsilon = 0.000001f;     //change this to meet your needs
```

Now, we need to change the definition of equality so that any value within Epsilon (either way) of being equal is equal:

```
{ Operator.Equal, (p,s) => (Math.Abs(float.Parse(p.TagValue) - float.Parse(s.TagValue)) < Epsilon) },
```

You'd need to do something similarly for "Unequal", and you should really use that same value in a calculation for the `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=` operators.

In any case, once you are finished, you could simply do something like this:

```
const int pollingTime = 50; //milliseconds
```

and this:

```
var test = operatorItems[step.Operator];

while (!test(spStep, pvStep))
{
    await Task.Delay(pollingTime);
}
```

Comment: please see my edit according to your answer. i believe i can now put all my recepi executing code inside execute function.

Comment: please see my state machine code which works fine for executing a recipe. but I still don't understand how I can go back and forward steps. https://pastebin.com/Xiuf1N5s can you please guide me on this?

Comment: @Gajarubanjeyakumar. When you start your recipe, don't go into a loop. Instead, start the first step. When you get to the first step, check if you are in automatic mode, if so, signal `Next`. When you signal Next, do what you'd do in the loop to get to the next step. There is no loop, only Next and Prev.

Comment: thankyou. but I get this unwanted result of starting 2 steps after the first step.

 https://pastebin.com/uaKg50cv